# How do I use a custom TaskAwaiter for tasks on .Net 4.5?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I can create my own TaskAwaiter with .Net 4.0 by providing an extension method GetAwaiter on Task, but when running the code with .Net 4.5 this is not possible.

The Task class on .Net 4.5 have a method called GetAwaiter, and my extension method would never be called.

---

<sub>My 1 comment:
I can create a custom awaiter on another class (not Task), but async methods can only return Task or void, and wrappring every task/async-method call is not pratical/elegant.</sub>

<sub>My 2 comment:
What I need is to AUTOMATICALLY save data when the Task is created (or awaited) and retrieve this data on the continuation method, WITHOUT changing the synchronization context.</sub>

<sub>My 3 comment:
Everything works as expected with .Net 4.0 and my custom TaskAwaiter.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this. Custom awaiters are intended for custom types (and even then, there's usually a better way of doing things). One alternative is to use an extension method for `Task`, similar to how `ConfigureAwait` works.

If you want to just carry local data through, then just use lambda variable capture.

If you want to carry through "ambient" data, then you can use `CallContext.LogicalSetData` and `CallContext.LogicalGetData`. However, you should only store immutable data there and that solution will *only* work on .NET 4.5. I have more [details on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).